# Python nested lists and recursion problem

Tags: python, recursion, boolean-logic

I posted this question under an alter yesterday not realising my account was still active after 9 months, sorry for the double post, i've fixed an error in my example pointed out by jellybean and i'll elaborate further on the context of the problem.

I'm trying to process a first order logic formula represented as nested lists and strings in python so that that its in disjunctive normal form,

i.e

```
[
    '&', 
    ['|', 'a', 'b'], 
    ['|', 'c', 'd']
]
```

turns into

```
[
    '|',
    [
        '|', 
        ['&', 'a', 'c'], 
        ['&', 'b', 'c']
    ], 
    [
        '|', 
        ['&', 'a', 'd'], 
        ['&', 'b', 'd']
    ]
]`
```

where `|` is ***or*** and `&` is ***and***.

currently im using a recursive implementation which does several passes over a formula until it can't find any nested 'or' symbols inside a list argument for 'ands'. Its being used to process a set of nested formulas represented as strings and lists for universal [computational tree logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_tree_logic) so it will not only have `|`s and `&`s but temporal operators.

This is my implementation, `performDNF(form)` is the entry point. Right now it performs a single pass over the formula with `dnfDistributivity()` which works for smaller inputs but when you use larger inputs the while loop checking function (`checkDistributivity()`) finds no `|`s inside of `&`s and terminates. Help anyone, this is driving me mad.

```
def dnfDistributivity(self, form):
    if isinstance(form, type([])):
        if len(form) == 3:
            if form[0] == '&':
                if form[1][0] == '|':
                    form = [
                               '|', 
                               ['&', form[2], form[1][1]], 
                               ['&', form[2], form[1][2]]
                           ]
                elif form[2][0] == '|':
                    form = [
                                '|', 
                                ['&', form[1], form[2][1]], 
                                ['&', form[1], form[2][2]]
                           ]
            form[1] = self.dnfDistributivity(form[1])
            form[2] = self.dnfDistributivity(form[2])
        elif len(form) == 2:
            form[1] = self.dnfDistributivity(form[1])
    return form

def checkDistributivity(self, form, result = 0):
    if isinstance(form, type([])):
        if len(form) == 3:
            if form[0] == '&':
                print "found &"
                if isinstance(form[1], type([])):
                    if form[1][0] == '|':
                        return 1
                elif isinstance(form[2], type([])):
                    if form[2][0] == '|':
                        return 1
                else:
                    result = self.checkDistributivity(form[1], result)
                    print result
                    if result != 1:
                        result = self.checkDistributivity(form[2], result)
                        print result
        elif len(form) == 2:
            result = self.checkDistributivity(form[1], result)
            print result
    return result

def performDNF(self, form):
    while self.checkDistributivity(form):
        form = self.dnfDistributivity(self.dnfDistributivity(form))
    return form
```

Comment: The previous post FlyingToaster is referring to is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787576/python-nested-lists-and-recursion-problem.
Although these two posting collected so far in excess of 70 views, there's been but one generic response.

Comment: Why go top down? If you put the recursion at the top, won't the "or" bits bubble up?

Comment: Its looks like regex to me "[ab][cd]" == "ac|bc|ad|bd", May be I dont know that logic at all though.

Comment: I gave the bottom up approach a try too but similarly to the top down it partially processed the formula in dnfDistributivity() and checkDistributivity() still misses that its only partially processed. As for the regex thats correct except for what i'm using the lists for requires a fairly rich language, i've been doing this in conjunction with lex/yacc but I need to process formulas after they've been parsed, i'm just not sure why checkDistributivity wouldn't be able to see that the last returned formula still contains a disjunctive operation nested with a conjunctive operation.

Comment: You should strive to post short, focussed questions rather than this kind of "please do my homework" question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

First, two general remarks about your code:

- Use `return True` instead of `return 1`.
- Use `isinstance(form, list)` instead of `isinstance(form, type([]))`.

Second, some other observations:

- I assume you also want to get rid of double negations. Currently your code doesn't do that.
- Likewise, you'll need to apply one of DeMorgan's laws to push negations to the leaves.

Aside from that, I think the readability of this code can be improved greatly. I'll give an alternative implementation which I believe to be correct. Let me know whether the code below works for you; I didn't go crazy with creating expressions, so I may have missed an edge case. Lastly, I will focus only on the regular propositional connectives. It should be clear how to apply transformations involving CTL-specific connectives.

1. Create a class `Op` which represents an operator (connective):

   ```
   class Op(list):
       def __init__(self, *args):
           super().__init__(args)
   ```

   The arguments to [`__init__`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) are the operands. This code uses [`super`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#super) as defined in [PEP 3135](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/) and works only in Python 3.x In Python 2.x, you'll have to use [`super`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) as defined in [PEP 367](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0367/):

   ```
   class Op(list):
       def __init__(self, *args):
           super(Op, self).__init__(args)
   ```
2. Create simple subclasses of `Op` for each operator. For debugging purposes you may want to implement a custom [`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method:

   ```
   class Neg(Op):
       def __str__(self):
           return '!(%s)' % tuple(self)
   class And(Op):
       def __str__(self):
           return '(%s) & (%s)' % tuple(self)
   class Or(Op):
       def __str__(self):
           return '(%s) | (%s)' % tuple(self)
   class AX(Op):
       def __str__(self):
           return 'AX (%s)' % tuple(self)
   ...
   ```

   Now the formula *!(a & b)* can be created as `Neg(And('a', 'b'))`.
3. Create *very simple* functions which apply a certain transformation *once*. This will keep the implementation clean. [Annotate](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) these functions which some information on how they should be applied. A *preorder* function should be applied from top to bottom: first transform the root of the expression tree, then recurse. A *postorder* function should be applied to an expression after it has been recursively applied to subexpressions. Use [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check the type of connectives.

   1. We start easy: the function `removeDoubleNeg` removes double negations:

      ```
      @expressionTransformation('postorder')
      def removeDoubleNeg(expr):
          if isinstance(expr, Neg) and isinstance(expr[0], Neg):
              return expr[0][0]
      ```
   2. Next, let's define one of DeMorgan's laws:

      ```
      @expressionTransformation('preorder')
      def deMorgan(expr):
          if isinstance(expr, Neg) and isinstance(expr[0], And):
              return Or(Neg(expr[0][0]), Neg(expr[0][1]))
      ```
   3. And now the function which this question is all about:

      ```
      @expressionTransformation('preorder', 'postorder')
      def distribute(expr):
          if isinstance(expr, And):
              if isinstance(expr[0], Or):
                  return Or(And(expr[0][0], expr[1]), And(expr[0][1], expr[1]))
              if isinstance(expr[1], Or):
                  return Or(And(expr[0], expr[1][0]), And(expr[0], expr[1][1]))
      ```

      Wow! That's a lot less code!
4. Okay, so how does this work? Observe that any naive implementation of an expression transformation *f* will involve boilerplate code:

   1. Test whether the argument is a connective (as opposed to a constant or variable).
   2. Attempt to apply *f* to the root of the expression tree.
   3. Recurse.
   4. Return the result.

   Depending on *f*, step 1 and 2 may need to be reversed (*postorder* instead of *preorder*). Still, every implementation of *f* will look alike. You will want to avoid boilerplate code, especially if you plan to define many more transformations. It is the lack of this boilerplate that made the functions defined in the previous step so concise (and thus easy to debug!). The decorators returned by the function `expressionTransformation` solved this problem. Its implementation is as follows:

   ```
   from functools import wraps
   def expressionTransformation(*args):
       def wrap(f):
           @wraps(f)
           def recursiveTransformation(expr):
               if not isinstance(expr, Op):
                   return expr
               if 'postorder' in args:
                   expr[:] = map(recursiveTransformation, expr)
               res = f(expr)
               expr = expr if res is None else res 
               if 'preorder' in args:
                   expr[:] = map(recursiveTransformation, expr)
               return expr
           return recursiveTransformation
       return wrap
   ```

   What happens here is the following:

   1. The function `expressionTransformation` returns a decorator (named `wrap`) which receives the transformation function `f` as its argument.
   2. `wrap` returns a recursive function `recursiveTransformation` which applies `f` to its argument `expr` only if this argument is a connective.
   3. Depending on the arguments `args` supplied to `expressionTransformation`, `f` will be applied *before* or *after* (or before **and** after) applying *f* to the subexpressions.
   4. The assumption is made that `f` may return `None` if no transformation is made.

   The function [`functools.wraps`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) is used to copy certain properties of `f`, such as its name, to `recursiveTransformation`. This functionality is non-essential.

   (Note that there are more efficient way to create preorder and postorder transformations than using the tests `'postorder' in args` and `'preorder' in args` over and over, but I chose this for clarity.)
5. That's all. We can now easily combine these functions (note that this function should not be decorated):

   ```
   def toDNF(expr):
       return distribute(removeDoubleNeg(deMorgan(expr)))
   ```
6. You can test the code with statements like these:

   ```
   toDNF(AX(And(Or('a', 'b'), And(Or('c', 'd'), Or('e', 'f')))))
   toDNF(Neg(And(Or(Neg(Neg('a')), 'b'), And(Or('c', 'd'), Or('e', 'f')))))
   ```

Comment: wow, that is some beautiful code, give me some time and I will analyse that approach but i'm very interested in what you've done from first glance. 

Also you are correct about the absence removal of double negatives and DeMorgans law, I had them as other methods of the overall class and removed them from the scope of the problem to simplify the issue.

Comment: ok, i've had some time to check it out and wrap my head around whats going on, great approach if you ask me, i've come across decorators before but had trouble wrapping my mind around the concept. After doing a bit of "sharpening my saw" I understand it. Cheers :)

Comment: @FlyingToaster: glad you like it! If this sufficiently answers your question, you can upvote the answer and mark it as accepted. Otherwise, feel free to point out what's missing :)

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
    elif len(form) == 2:
        result = self.checkDistributivity(form[1], result)
        print result
```

Shouldn't that be:

```
    elif len(form) == 2:
        result_1 = self.checkDistributivity(form[1], result)
        result_2 = self.checkDistributivity(form[2], result) 
        if result_1 or result_2:
            return 1
```

Comment: ah, when the formula has 2 items in the list its considered a unary operation, the first list item would be the token (in the case of ctl this would be cases like ['AG', 'a'] or ['AF', 'c'] where AG and AF are temporal operators. You only need to process the 2nd argument, or index value 1.